# git commit contains 2 equal filepaths with different case?

Tags: git

I'm new to git and I do not understand how this happened.

This is my commit:

```
$ git show --pretty="" --name-only 023353a633108f013e0800849abn07d11d9b4babc
Projects/Tools/TCS-Modularized.xml
projects/tools/Input-ALL.xls
```

So not a problem for Windows (unfortunately?!) where both files are in the same folder, but for Linux aren't those 2 different folders? 
How did this even happen?

When I navigate to the folder using `bash` it shows:

```
MINGW64 /d/gitRepo/projects/tools (master)
```

but Windows Explorer shows:

```
D:\gitRepo\Projects\Tools
```

Now I have no idea how to fix that, because this repo is checked out on TeamCity and the Mapping is for `Projects/Tools` which causes the `Input-ALL.xls` not to be checked out. So this is an existing issue, I hotfixed it by mapping the lowercase path too, but that's a solution I don't wanna keep.

When using `TortoiseGit-Rename` it's CamelCase already, how can I fix it, i tried to commit the .xsl again, but the path stays lowercase.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Windows Explorer can't distinguish `Tools` from `tools`. You'd better rename one of them and commit the renaming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this from a Linux system (where `tools/` and `Tools/` are two separate folders)

Otherwise, you can try doing some phony file moving, such as :

```
# from bash :
mkdir temp
git mv tools/Input-All.xls temp
git mv temp/Input-All.xls Tools/

# check 'git status' to see if the path fits what you expect :
git status

# if this "worked", you should see :
R  tools/Input-All.xls -> Tools/Input-All.xls
```

(Then add + commit + push)

Comment: thats the way I had to solve it now. First modify the file, then check with git status it's actual case-sensitive path and correct it by `git mv` to the desired path. 
I figured this happened because sometimes I navigate in git bash like `cd tools` which does work and due to Windows shows you all the files you expected even though you are actually in the wrong "path", but after a commit the path is also `tools` and the file is missing on the Linux system. So I try to use `t[TAB]` now to get `Tools` and pay attention on the case of my bash path :)